# ZendService Twitter fails on Client connect()

Tags: php, curl, twitter, zend-framework2, zend-http-client

Having problems connecting with the Twitter API through ZendService/Twitter/Twitter.

```
Error:  Fatal error: Call to a member function connect() on a non-object in somepath/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Http/Client.php on line 1358



$config = array (
                'access_token' => array (
                        'token' => 'dummy',
                        'secret' => 'dummy' 
                ),
                'oauth_options' => array (
                        'consumerKey' => 'dummy',
                        'consumerSecret' => 'dummy' 
                ),
                'http_client_options' => array (
                        'adapter' => 'Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Curl',
                        'curloptions' => array (
                                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
                                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false 
                        ) 
                ) 
        );

        $twitter = new Twitter ( $config );
        print_r ($twitter->account->verifyCredentials ());
```

Using curl 7.26.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) OpenSSL/1.0.1e
PHP 5.4.35 on ZF 2.3.3

**Update 1:** Removing the access_token section returns an "Bad Authentication data" message. Enabling it again, will throw the atal error: Call to a member function connect() on a non-object in somepath/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Http/Client.php on line 1358

Answer (score 1):

Twitter **allows only SSL connections** in Twitter API endpoints. This detail is documented [here](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/ssl). So, you need to set your adapter options to meet the SSL protocol requirements.

Try this:

```
'http_client_options' => array (
    'adapter' => 'Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Curl',
    'curloptions' => array (
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true,
        CURLOPT_CAINFO => '/path/to/certs/ca-bundle.pem'
    ) 
),
```

When verifying a remote host, you need to provide one or more certificates of trusted CAs. The value 2 for `VERIFYHOST` option is required to checking the existence of a common name and also verifies that it matches the hostname provided. Use 1 for only check existence of name in the SSL peer certificate.

You may also want to read more about configuring SSL connections using Curl adapter in [this nice tutorial](http://blog.debug.cz/2012/11/https-connections-with-zend-framework-2.html).

Comment: Nothing changed after adding a reference       CURLOPT_CAINFO => '/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt'

Comment: Interesting. Did you try running this on a production or staging server? You may also need to create a self-signed certificate for your local development environment. For example: http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html